# Why do we have an MLP tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Ran across a question with the `mlp` tag today.

As of asking this question, the [`mlp`](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mlp) tag has 52 questions and no tag description, and the (synonymous, I think) [`neural_network`](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neural-network) tag has 2,785 questions and a reasonable description.

Should we remove the `mlp` tag? And maybe edit the description of the `neural_networks` tag to mention the MLPs, if we don't want to drop that  name (which is somewhat familiar, through SKLearn)?

Comment: `mlp` is not technically synonymous with a neural net. It is a type of a neural net and used for a feedforward ANNs

Comment: So it is synonymous with DNNs, and maybe that tag description should say so explicitly

Comment: Please feel free to propose an edit on the tag description

Comment: Ok, I submitted a proposal